# bootstrap 4 and popover lying outside of the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

How to have a bootstrap popover always contained in the screen?
Below a popover that lying outside of the screen

[image]

http://s.codepen.io/juavenel/debug/LkjPYL

Comment: Post the code please

Answer (score 2):

add this to solve the problem:

```
constraints: [ { to: 'scrollParent', pin: true } ]
```